# Joda Time + Android - how to set hour and day for repeated alarm avent in the same?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, jodatime

I'm newbie in the Joda time library.

I woul like to ask how can i do following code using Joda Time?

```
Calendar firingCal = Calendar.getInstance();
                // Each day at predefined hour
                firingCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfSending); 
                // Each day at predefined minute                                                
                firingCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutesOfSending); 
                // Each day at predefined second                    
                firingCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

So after the convertion on the milliseconds is Repeating alarm is alarm executed in the same time (by mobile device) across the differentc UTC zones.

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firingCal , AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingAlarm1Intent);
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I didn't understand what exactly do you want to achieve..

Comment: How to set using Joda time same value as using example using the calendar (firingCal variable).

Answer (score 0):

You want to convert to Gregorial Time, according to joda-time documentation the preferred method to use is to call this: [AbstractDateTime#toCalendar](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/base/AbstractDateTime.html#toCalendar(java.util.Locale)).

example

```
  DateTime jodaTimeVar = new DateTime(1, 1, 0, hourOfSending, minutesOfSending, 0, 0);
  alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, jodaTimeVar.toCalendar().getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingAlarm1Intent);
```

Comment: Could you please provide some example? Their documentation seems to me wrong readable.

Comment: use it like that alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, jodaTimeVAR.toCalendar(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingAlarm1Intent);

Comment: Thanks, but how to configure the jodaTimeVar??

Comment: jodaTimeVar.toCalendar() should to return Long for using in larmManager.setRepeating

Comment: then and that you have write is wrong, you have to use calendar.getTimeInMillis(). I didn't checked the setRepeating method...

Comment: I did it, but now it is throwing exception :
 Value 0 for monthOfYear must be in the range [1,12] . Joda seems to be more difficult than using Calendar.

Comment: use 1 not 0 then. i haven't use Joda never actually, i'm just suggesting solutions

Comment: I dont think so it is the right approach. 1'st month is the January.